# Trying to understand memory management on the iOS platform

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, ipad, memory-management

Here's a block of code that has leaks...

```
NSString *filename = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@.png", sketchID];
CGImageRef imageRef = CGBitmapContextCreateImage(paintView.canvas.mBitmapContext);
UIImage* image = [[UIImage alloc] initWithCGImage:imageRef];
NSData* imageData = UIImagePNGRepresentation(image);
```

1. Where are they?
2. In general, how can I tell so I don't create leaks in the future?
3. What's the proper way to fix them?

Thanks so much!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

AS far as I can tell you have memleaks in:

```
CGImageRef imageRef = CGBitmapContextCreateImage(paintView.canvas.mBitmapContext);
```

You need to call [CGContextRelease](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/GraphicsImaging/Reference/CGContext/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/c/func/CGContextRelease). Check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1434714/another-iphone-cgbitmapcontextcreateimage-leak) SO question out.

You need to release `image` aswell. After creating `imageData`, do:

```
[image release];
```

You don't have to release `fileName` since you are not explicitly allocating memory for it. It will autorelease when variable falls out of scope. There are naming conventions in objective-c that will tell you when you will have to release and when you don't. Check out Apple documentation for it.

Hope it helps.

Comment: thanks, pablo.  question, why don't i ahve to release imageData?  or filename?

Comment: Updated the answer with a little commend on filename. You should release imageData after you are done with it.

Comment: Thanks again, Pablo.  Are you sure I need to release imageData?  I figured I would haven't release imageData for the same reason I don't have to release fileName.  Your thoughts?

Comment: True. According to doc (http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/uikit/reference/UIKitFunctionReference/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/c/func/UIImagePNGRepresentation) the memory will be autoreleased.

Comment: -1 You don't have to release the context; you have to release the image.

Answer (score 0):

The general rule is that when you call `alloc` then you need a corresponding `release`. The exception is when you call `autorelease`.  Also, when you use convenience methods, such as 'stringWithFormat'.

Comment: Um, you should release. *Never* explicitly deallocate an object unless you really know what you're doing.