# "Potential leak of an object" when using Core Graphics

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-graphics

My app is drawing a shadow using the following code:

```
-(void)drawShadow:(CGContextRef)context rect:(CGRect)rect{

    CGContextSaveGState(context);

    //Set color of current context
    [[UIColor blackColor] set];

    //Set shadow and color of shadow
    CGContextSetShadowWithColor(context, CGSizeMake(0, 2), 3, [[UIColor colorWithWhite:0 alpha:0.5] CGColor]);

    CGContextFillEllipseInRect(context, rect);

    CGContextClipToMask(context, rect, CGBitmapContextCreateImage(context));

    CGContextRestoreGState(context); // Warning shows in this line

}
```

When I run Product > Analyze, it marks the last instruction of this block with the message: "Potential leak of an object". When I remove that line, it shows the same message but in the closing bracket.

Any idea of what I'm doing wrong?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think it's the `CGBitmapContextCreateImage` that is leaking.

Try assigning it to a local variable and then calling `CGImageRelease` with it once you've clipped to mask.

[Another iPhone - CGBitmapContextCreateImage Leak](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1434714/another-iphone-cgbitmapcontextcreateimage-leak)

Answer (score 0):

`chedabob`'s answer worked! Here's the final code:

```
-(void)drawShadow:(CGContextRef)context rect:(CGRect)rect{
    CGContextSaveGState(context);
    //Set color of current context
    [[UIColor blackColor] set];
    //Set shadow and color of shadow
    CGContextSetShadowWithColor(context, CGSizeMake(0, 2), 3, [[UIColor colorWithWhite:0 alpha:0.5] CGColor]);
    CGContextFillEllipseInRect(context, rect);

    CGImageRef bitmap = CGBitmapContextCreateImage(context);
    CGContextClipToMask(context, rect, bitmap);
    CGContextRestoreGState(context);

    CGImageRelease(bitmap);
}
```